# If $A \subseteq B$, then is $M \otimes A \subseteq M \otimes B$?

Tags: modules, tensor-products, flatness

Let $A, B$ be $R$-modules. If $A \subseteq B$, then is $M \otimes A \subseteq M \otimes B$? What happens if $A$ is given to be a flat module?

Comment: @Lelouch: tensor product is right exact. It's left exact iff $M$ is flat.

Comment: @Geet: for fixed $M$, this is true for all $A \subseteq B$ iff $M$ is flat.

Comment: It is also true if $B/A$ is flat, for any $M$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, sorry. But what is a counterexample when $M$ is not flat, for example take $M = \mathbb{Z}_2, R = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Lelouch: take $B = \mathbb{Z}, A = 2 \mathbb{Z}$.