# Interpretation of $B\otimes M$ when $B\subset A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, exact-sequence, flatness

Let us fix the setting to avoid ambiguity. Let $R$ be a commutative, unital ring. All tensor products will be considered for modules over $R$.

Let $A$ be an $R$-module, $B$ a submodule. Now, is $A\otimes M\subset B\otimes M$ ?

The question to the answer is given succinctly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920152/if-a-subseteq-b-then-is-m-otimes-a-subseteq-m-otimes-b). Essentially, flatness will guarantee it, as you can think of the inclusion as an injective module homomorphism, which will remain an injective morphism after tensoring with a flat module. But that is not all.

My **main question** is, is it common to use $B\otimes M$ to represent the submodule of $A\otimes M$, generated by elementary tensors of the form $\{b\otimes m: b\in B\subset A, m\in M\}$?

(If it is not clear why this distinction is important, consider the module homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ given by multiplication by two, then the image of this homomorphism is $2\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, which is the same as $\mathbb{Z}$, so $2\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ . However, the elementary tensors mentioned above will just be zero, as $2n\otimes \bar{m}=2(n\otimes\bar{m})=n\otimes\overline{2m}=0$, so the submodule generated is the zero module.)

Because I am quite confident that that is what is happening in the accepted answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953452/basic-question-about-the-image-and-kernel-of-tensor-products). This post has caused me a good amount of confusion precisely because of the example mentioned above.

Comment: I disagree with the last paragraph.  I don't see that happening in the post in the second link.  There's $M=M^\prime=\Bbb{Z}, N=\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, a map $f:M\to M^\prime$ given by $f(x)=2x$ and a map $f\otimes 1:M\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} N\to M^\prime\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} N$.

Comment: @ChadK Yes, that is ok. So the image of $f\otimes 1$, which is a sub module of $M’\otimes N$, is zero, but the module (Im($f)\otimes N)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Oh, I see, you were talking about the first identity, not the counterexample.  You're right, $\operatorname{Im}(f)\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} N$ is *not* a submodule of $M^\prime\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} N$.  The first identity is invalid.

Comment: and $\operatorname{Ker}(f) \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} N$ is *not* a submodule of $M\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} N$ either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the linked post. To answer your original question first, you should always interpret $B\otimes M$ as the tensor product of $B$ with $M$, not as some misleading notation for a particular subgroup of $A\otimes M$. $B$ itself is a group, so we should not ambiguate the product $B\otimes M$ with some 'relative' notion like $\langle b\otimes m:b\in B,m\in M\rangle\subset A\otimes M$ as this will depend on $A$. However, wearing our categorical hats, what matters in this discussion - as what matters for the $\ker$ discussion - is the associated maps. It *is* true that the associated map $B\otimes M\to A\otimes M$ has image $\langle b\otimes m\rangle_{b,m}$. However, don't be fooled: *the tensor relations for $\otimes$ are different in $B\otimes M$ to $A\otimes M$*.

---

To discuss the linked post:

Say $f:A\to B$. $\ker(f)\otimes M\not\subset\ker(f\otimes1)$ in general; not in any natural way. There is a natural map $\ker(f)\otimes M\to A\otimes M$ which is killed by $f\otimes1:A\otimes M\to B\otimes M$, which the linked post implicitly shows, but this does not mean $\ker(f)\otimes M\subset\ker(f\otimes1)$. Rather, it just means there is an induced natural map $\ker(f)\otimes M\to\ker(f\otimes1)$ but this map is certainly not injective in general, nor is it surjective!

$\ker(f)\otimes M\to\ker(f\otimes1)$ injects iff. $\ker(f)\otimes M\to A\otimes M$ injects; this holds when $\mathsf{Tor}(\mathrm{im}(f),M)=0$ but is potentially false otherwise. $\ker(f)\otimes M\to\ker(f\otimes1)$ surjects iff. $\mathrm{im}(f)\otimes M\to B\otimes M$ injects and this again need not hold; $\mathrm{im}(f)\otimes M\not\subset\mathrm{im}(f\otimes1)$ in general, in fact $\mathrm{im}(f\otimes1)$ is a *quotient* of $\mathrm{im}(f)\otimes M$.

Try the map associated to multiplication by $2$, $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$; let's take this to be our $f:A\to B$. Let's also take $M=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

$A\otimes M\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\cong B\otimes M$ in such a way that $f\otimes 1$ is the zero map. $\ker(f)\otimes M\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ so you might be tempted to say $\ker(f)\otimes M=\ker(f\otimes1)$ but the associated map (and **this** is what matters; we don't really care if two groups are abstractly and unnaturally isomorphic, we usually want to know the maps that provide the isomorphism; also, categorically "$\ker(f\otimes1)$" carries information about a map, not just an object) $\ker(f)\otimes M\to A\otimes M=\ker(f\otimes1)$ is in fact the zero map; we do not get the natural inclusion. It is neither surjective nor injective! Similarly $\mathrm{im}(f)\otimes M\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is *not* a subgroup of $\mathrm{im}(f\otimes1)=0$.